# Type of cable needed for new audio/video port on Model B+?

Tags: video

Just wondering what kind of cable I need to output audio and video using the new AV jack on the RPi model B+. I'm assuming it would look like a headphone cord but split to RCA or similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would likely be a 4-pole RCA cable, similar to this one -

http://www.techbuy.com.au/p/160072/CABLES_RCA/Sansai/MP-9103.asp

However you will need to check pinouts on the cable to make sure it matches with what the Pi is outputting.

I found this blog post - http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/07/raspberry-pi-model-b-3-5mm-audiovideo-jack/ - that details it