# Raspberry pi 2 has a unified RCA and audio jack. What cable should i use to connect to an analog TV?

Tags: raspbian, composite-video, connectors

[image: Notice the Audio jack is also the Composite Video jack]

A 3.5 mm Male to an RCA Composite 3-pin cable was suggested, but i've read that this sort of cable needs modifications to work with the Raspberry Pi 2. Can anyone please give me a detailed description of my problem and fix?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Indeed it is. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate.  The Pi 2 is not a model B+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Pi2 video/audio socket is actually the same as the earlier B+ model.

See [Type of cable needed for new audio/video port on Model B+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22383/type-of-cable-needed-for-new-audio-video-port-on-model-b)